# Php check for specific word and change color

Tags: php, jquery

I have never programmed in php before but I just found out that i need to edit the wp-admin page of a word press site and it MUST be done in php.

Actually what i need to do is change the color of a specific word.For example I need "cars" to be always on red. In jQuery that could be something like this:

```
  $('p:contains("cars")').css('color', 'red');
```

Can anyone help me to write this in php please

Comment: Why do this on php?

Comment: Because it should be placed on functions.php to be accessible for the admin page...

if it is done on jquery it is not accessible to wp-admin page

Answer (score 3):

You can use strpos and do something like that :

```
$text = "some text containing cars word";

if (strpos($text , 'cars') !== false) {
    $style = 'style="color:red"';
} 
else {
    $style = "";
}

echo "<p ".$style.">".$text."</p>";
```

If the text contains "cars" word, strpos() will return the position of the word in the text. Else it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to replace just words **cars** colored by red use preg_replace with flag *g* in pathern Regex to match all the words (cars) in the paragraph and replace them with red colored span. if you want change all paragraph use the code suggested by [Titi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14731920/titi)

```php
<?php
    $paragraph = "<p>we all know cars faster than bikes!<p>";
    echo preg_replace('/(cars)/g', '<span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $paragraph);
    //<p>we all know <span style="color:red;">cars</span> faster than bikes!<p>
?>
```

Comment: I am afraid this is more complicated than this because the <p> is part of a table which is created based on clients choise.... just to give an idea:

Comment: sorry i didn't get why you should even use php to deal this, js or even jQuery is suitable if you are dealing with front-end content show to client.

Comment: I am afraid this is more complicated than this because  <p> is part of a table which is created based on clients choise.... just to give an idea:

`<tbody id="order_line_items">
  <tr class="item " data-order_item_id="15">
 <td class="thumb">
  <a class="wc-order-item-name">engine</a>  
    <div class="view" style="display:block;">        
                    <p>-drive</p><p>                </p></div>
                                            <div style="display:inline-flex;">
                    <p>-cars</p><p>                </p></div>
                                       `

Comment: @ SteveEverst 

I need to edit wp-admin webpage. To do this i have to use 
`add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );` which shoud be placed on functions.php which is written in php. I am not sure if `enqueue_my_scripts'` can be a jQuery function...

Comment: it seems you're using  wordpress, sorry i don't have experience with wordpress how it works :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use js script in the WordPress admin_enqueue_scripts.

Place your script into your plugin folder and then use it like that :

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/myscript.js');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');
```

This way, it calls a PHP function that calls a js file

Here is the official documentation about that : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

There are some posts about that at the bottom of the page.